# Why is the cmd closing when I try to use an if/else?

Tags: batch-file

So I really don't know much of anything about coding.
I'm trying to make a stupid little text based game using a batch file but I immediately ran into an issue where as soon as an answer is given for the first prompt, the cmd just immediately closes out. I can't figure out the issue.
Thanks for your help.

```
@echo off
echo You are Ryan Manfold, an American astronaut and captain of the Mayflower II.
echo The MFII will be the first manned space vessel to reach Mars. You and your six crewmates are 7 months into your 13 month journey.
echo The ship is comprised of three large rings which spin to simulate gravity, and a cylindrical module that the rings connect to.
echo You are asleep in your cabin in Ring 1, near the head of the ship.
pause
cls
:start
echo You wake up in the dark and reach over to flick on the lights.
echo The digital clock on the wall reads 9:23 AM, work shift doesn't start until 10.
echo Do you get up now anyway and head to the mess hall or do you go back to bed?
echo 1. Go to mess hall
echo 2. go back to sleep
set /p wake="Which One?:"
if %wake%==1 (
pause
goto insomnia
)else(
pause
goto next
)
:next
if %wake%==2 (
goto meetingone
)else(
echo That input is invalid
echo please try again.
pause
goto start
)
:insomia
echo you walk out of your room.
pause
exit
```

Comment: `cmd` is a bit picky with spaces. Read the output of `if /?` for proper syntax. (`)else(` gives a syntax error that leads to termination of the script). For troubleshooting don't run per mouseclick. Open a `cmd` window and run it manually from there. The window will stay open enabling you to read the errormessages.

Comment: Try `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start and `endlocal` at the end

Comment: @cup: why that? There is nothing in the code that requires delayed expansion.

Comment: You should take a look at the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command. It does its own error handling and won't accept invalid choices.

Comment: If you're new then just avoid all the nasty legacies of cmd and learn PowerShell instead

Comment: You do not need the `else(` statements which are causing your issues anyhow. For example: `14.` `set /p "wake=Which one?:"`, `15.` `if "%wake%" == "1" (`, `16.` `pause`, `17.` `goto insomnia`, `18.` `)`, `19.` `pause`, `20.` `:next`, `21.` `if "%wake%" =="2" goto meetingone`, `22.` `echo That input is invalid`, `23.` `echo please try again.`, `24.` `pause`, `25.` `goto start`, and `26.` `:insomnia`. Although this would be more robust and better: `14.` `%systemroot%\system32\choice.exe /c 12 /n "Which One?:"`, `15.` `if errorlevel 2 goto meetingzone`, `16.` `pause`, and `17.` `:insomnia`.

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces between the bracket and the else: `) else (`

Also if you opened a command prompt and ran the batch file you'd be able to see the error `else( was unexpected at this time.` but if you're double clicking on the file it'll exit before you see the error.

Comment: Technically, all that is needed is `)else (`; _a separating space is not required immediately after the closing parenthesis_.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to an inexistent function. You instruct the bat to go to "insomnia" but there is no "insomnia" function there is only a "insomia" function. So the problem is a typo.

Comment: Questions that can be answered by correcting a simple typo should be voted to be closed or flagged, because they are not going to be helpful for future visitors here…